# Why is FLVPlayback with no skin render as invisible?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flvplayback

I run the following code using Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5, Flash Player 11.2.202.235, ActionScript 3:

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
var localVideo:FLVPlayback = ...; // Instantiated by the IDE

[..]

localVideo.getVideoPlayer(localVideo.activeVideoPlayerIndex);
videoPlayer.attachCamera(camera);
```

Normally, the the local camera's feed shows up inside `localVideo`, but if I set the FLVPlayback skin to "none" the video component doesn't render at all (it's fully transparent). All I'm trying to do is render a FLVPlayback for a live video feed without any buttons. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation it turns out that when skin is set to "none" you need to make explicitly mark the video player as visible:

```
videoPlayer.visible = true;
```

Does anyone know why that is?